# Mysql rank position

Tags: php, mysql, rank

Database:

```
id  first_name  points
1   Bob          12
2   Jane             50
3   Jack             2
4   Bill             10
5   Nick             62
6   Kathy            18
7   Steve            42
8   Anne             52
```

Script:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","lol");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("st", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name,points,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY points DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['first_name'] . "  " . $row['points'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What i get;

```
Nick 62
Anne 52
Jane 50
Steve 42
Kathy 18
Bob 12
Bill 10
Jack 2
```

---

Now i need to add to user position rank (something like top function)
example:

```
Nick 62  Top 1
Anne 52  Top 2
Jane 50  Top 3
Steve 42 Top 4 and so on.....
Kathy 18
Bob 12
Bill 10
Jack 2
```

---

Comment: What's the question? Looking at your SQL, I'd say that `$row['rank']` should contain the value you're interested in printing.

Comment: What about people with the same amount of points, should they be tied in rank or one higher than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$position = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['first_name'] . "  " . $row['points'] . "  Top ".$position;
  echo "<br />";
  $position++;
  }
```

Comment: this does not always work, if the results are paginated, then position gets reset to 1 at the start of each page.

Comment: @bowlerae yes, but there's nothing about pagination in this question. Also if 2 or more results have same rank You need to mark it something like `1,2,3—5,3—5,3—5,6,7`. But there's nothing about it in this question too. Don't try to find difficulty in easy question :) Any way You can edit first line and add something like `$position = ($page-1)*$per_page + 1;` and my code will work fine. Have a good day.

Comment: I'm curious because I need a help with ranking to and no one has addressed this, I don't want to ask a new question and be hasseled because it's essentially the same question.

Comment: Paging is different question with nuances, that will not be strange to ask how to combine logical elements(paging/ranking/sorting/etc) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From your query i added `TOP` word using `CONCAT` function in MySQL.
try this:

```
SELECT   first_name,
         points,
         CONCAT('TOP ',@curRank := @curRank + 1) AS rank
FROM     person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY points DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","lol");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("st", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name,points FROM person ORDER BY points DESC");

$rank=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['points'] . " Top " . $rank++;
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: this does not always work, if the results are paginated, then rank gets reset to 1 at the start of each page.

Comment: There is no mentioning of pagination in the OQ, and the query without a LIMIT claude rules it out. Querying with `FROM (SELECT @curRank := 0)` has exactly the same effect as my $rank=1. Thanks for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider actually extracting and printing out the rank:

```
echo $row['first_name'] . "  " . $row['points']. " Top {$row['rank']}";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  $top = 1;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo $row['first_name'] . "  " . $row['points']." TOP ".$top ;
     echo "<br />";

     $top++;
   }
```

Comment: this does not always work, if the results are paginated, then top gets reset to 1 at the start of each page.